# Upserting salesforce check from Mule4

Tags: salesforce, dataweave, upsert, mule4

I am trying to upsert a salesforce custom object which is a check via java object.

Am trying below code:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
[{
Success__c: true as Boolean
}]
```

but the salesforce object taking it as false after every successful upsert.

[image]

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Is that all you are sending? Is the SF response ok? You need to send an ID usually so SF knows what to update.

Comment: Are you using the Salesforce Connector? If yes, what Salesforce operation (component) are you using upsert the data?